# Div follow scroll issue: scroll jump back to window top

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar

I've found and adapted this method to have my div follow down the scroll bar, only after a certain point is reached:

```
$.fn.followFrom = function (pos, left_fixed, left_absolute) {
var $this = this,
    $window = $(window);

    $window.scroll(function (e) {
        if ($window.scrollTop() < pos) {
            $this.css({ // no move
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 400,
                left: left_absolute
            });
        } else { // move
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 220,
                left: left_fixed
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Strangely (or not?), it works only when my div has content to its right.
But when it's the bottom element on the screen, then when scrolling and position is reached, hop the scroll bar jumps back to the top, which is a very frustrating user experience.

The context is a search page, where I have a map in my moving div on the left, and the search results on the right. So I want that when scrolling down the results, the map stays visible on the left.

So it works only when there are results AND the results height is bigger than the map's height. But as soon as the results' height gets shorter, then I get the jump.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried spelling window properly on the third line?

Comment: He probably has, since it works under certain circumstances.

Comment: Why don't you prepare a demo page for us (e.g. a jsFiddle) ? It is not very clear the way you describe it.

Comment: Ok I think I am beginning to figure out what's going on here. So when the div position is set to Fixed, then it's removed from the page flow, and the scroll bar apparently wants to disappear. That triggers a back to top jump, and resets the div back to previous position

Comment: That does not happen when results are there, because then with the results, the page's height is big enough, and removing the div from the flow does not remove the scroll bar.

Comment: Exactly ! See how you can work this out yourself (*and* have fun too) ? If you have found a solution to prevent this unwanted behaviour, consider posting it and marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to spot it easily. If still looking for the solution, show us some code and we might be able to propose one :)

Comment: i'm having the same issue and land here for solution, but may be @Nicolas did't solve it yet ?

Comment: in your else condition add bottom margin or padding to div that is scrollable, this solved my issue don't know if there is better way